# Microsoft Graph API - How can I use 'skiptoken'

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

It is bringing messages and replies to certain team's channel ID.

use this,

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{teamId}/channels/{channelId}/messages/{messageId}/replies?$top=50
```

If we get more than 50 results, it returns @odata.nextLink contains 'skiptoken'

like this..

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{teamId}/channels/{channelId}/messages/{messageId}/replies?$top=50&$skiptoken=ABCDEFG1234
```

But What I want to do is to use 'skiptoken' in c# code.

I tried,

```
 var replies = await graphClient.Teams[teamId].Channels[channel.Id].Messages[chatId].Replies
           .Request()
           .Top(50)
           .Skiptoken(skiptoken)
           .GetAsync();
```

This code returns an error.

- IChatMessageRepliesCollectionRequest does not include a definition of 'skiptoken'.

How can I use 'skiptoken'? Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: You can try this
*************************************************************
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
{
 new QueryOption("$skiptoken", "MSwwLDE1OTgwMzU4MTE4OTQ")
};

var replies = await graphClient.Teams["d3b31e36-d63d-4bbe-9478-b4cc7cb17a3d"].Channels["19:342b9f379eb340048b16d9859d9e3712@thread.tacv2"].Messages["1598032654892"].Replies
 .Request(queryOptions)
 .GetAsync();
**********************************************************
Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi Hyeon_, Please let us know if you are still facing the issue :)-.

Comment: Hi Hyeon_, Please let us know if that resolves your issue so that I can change it as answer and others can get benefited from it :)-

Comment: Yes Resolved! How to change to answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code.

```
var queryOptions = new List<QueryOption>() 
{ 
new QueryOption("$skiptoken", "MSwwLDE1OTgwMzU4MTE4OTQ") 
}; 
var replies = await graphClient.Teams["d3b31e36-d63d-4bbe-9478-b4cc7cb17a3d"].Channels["19:342b9f379eb340048b16d9859d9e3712@thread.tacv2"].Messages["1598032654892"].Replies 
.Request(queryOptions) 
.GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```cs
await graphClient.Teams[teamId].Channels[channel.Id].Messages[chatId].Replies.WithUrl(OdataNextLink).Request().GetAsync()
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**