# How to use SkipToken with Microsoft SDK?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-sdks

How to use SkipToken with MicrosoftSDK? *QueryParameters.SkipToken* do not exists.

Official documentation do not show how to use it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?tabs=csharp#skiptoken-parameter

```
string skipToken = "..";
var ret = await graphClient.Groups.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
  requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Top = 5;
  requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.SkipToken = skipToken;
});
```

*.Request(queryOptions)* doesnt exist too (solution from [Microsoft Graph API - How can I use 'skiptoken'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63718595/microsoft-graph-api-how-can-i-use-skiptoken))

Answer (score 0):

Skiptoken is a query parameter for delta queries:

```
string skipToken = "..";
var result = await graphClient.Groups.Delta.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Skiptoken = skipToken;
});
```

I would recommend to start with this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-groups?tabs=csharp).

Btw. There is a bug in SDK v5 and `Skiptoken` parameter is missing for group's delta. Bug reported [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/2014).

Comment: I think Delta will not solve it: Delta query enables applications to discover newly created, updated, or deleted entities without performing a full read of the target resource with every request.

I am using skiptoken on more calls: graphClient.Education.Schools do not support it too

Comment: @TomasKanok What is the expected behavior when using skiptoken for group queries? Could you provide example where do you use skiptoken?

Comment: I have project where I need to change HTTP API calls to C#. API call is working fine: "/groups?$top=5&$skiptoken=" + skipToken. How to do it in C# with Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient?

Comment: actually I use top=999 but we have more groups and it fail when I try to take more...

Comment: @TomasKanok I'm thinking about PageIterator: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#pageiterator whether it can help you